# One file has indentention of 2 spaces instead of 4

Tags: visual-studio-code

All my files are indented properly except for one. Is there any way I can do it without inserting spaces manually now?

In settings http://prntscr.com/ltf7z3  everything looks okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bottom right, in the bar where it say the line number and the column, you'll see a text saying something like `Spaces: 2` (or 4, depending on the file).

Click on it, select `Indent using spaces` from the menu that pops up and type `4` as the number of spaces.

The use the command palette to do `Reindent lines`.

Comment: Thank you! It's crazy I never realised there is this bar there.